# Error compiling code using LLVM

Tags: haskell, compilation, llvm

I am trying to compile the code presented in [here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=mandelbrot&lang=ghc&id=2) using the make shown at the end of the web page but I am getting the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mandelbrot.hs, mandelbrot.o )

<no location info>:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM
```

I checked the settings file of ghc and found that were like this:

```
 ("LLVM llc command", ""),
 ("LLVM opt command", "")
```

So I changed to map the commands as follows:

```
 ("LLVM llc command", "llc"),
 ("LLVM opt command", "opt")
```

But now I am getting a slightly different error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mandelbrot.hs, mandelbrot.o )

<no location info>:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM
```

Searched on the web for probable causes but the results point to old bug reports where it says this issue was fixed.

I don't have any experience with LLVM and don't know how to procede.

I am using Windows 7 64bits with The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3.

Comment: What version of GHC are you using?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Do you have LLVM installed and in your path?  Try `llvm-config --version`.  If this doesn't print out a version number then you don't have LLVM installed or set up properly.

Comment: @bheklilr, I tried the command in the command prompt and got nothing. Tried it on ghc and got just the ghc version. Isn't LLVM bundled together with ghc?

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion not that I know of. It has llvm support but does not come bundled with it.

Comment: How did you install GHC?  (Did you use the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html)?)

Comment: Same problem on OS X. If you drop the `-fllvm` then it builds fine. Rumor has it that LLVM has a tiny benefit but I can't verify the rumor because of this problem. I do have LLVM 3.5 installed with homebrew but it doesn't link by default because it can mess with other programs. If I force it into my path using `brew link --force llvm` then the build fails with lots of errors and eventual `LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!` May be a whole can of worms here.

Comment: @Rufflewind correct, I installed it using the Haskell Platform.

Comment: The `-fllvm` flag tells GHC to use LLVM as the backend. Haskell Platform doesn't include LLVM. Have you installed LLVM separately?

Comment: @Rufflewind I think that solves the issue. Thought it came preinstalled after seeing some comments on the Internet that it came bundled with GHC.

Comment: @Rufflewind installed it but still observing the same error.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion Is LLVM in your PATH variable?

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion What happens if you run GHC with `-v3`?

Comment: @Rufflewind lots of verbose and compiles fine (I did this without including -fllvm).

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion Include both `-v3` and `-fllvm`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63675/discussion-between-oneeyequestion-and-rufflewind).

Answer (score -1):

Not really answering your question but I got it to build with LLVM 3.4.2 on my Mac (LLVM 3.5 did not work). It does seem LLVM has some substantial benefits for this.

With LLVM

```
$ time ./Mandlebrot +RTS -N4 -RTS 16000 > /dev/null

real    0m10.635s
user    0m36.169s
sys 0m0.167s
```

Without LLVM

```
$ time ./Mandlebrot-nollvm +RTS -N4 -RTS 16000 > /dev/null

real    0m16.044s
user    1m0.704s
sys 0m0.165s
```

Sorry it doesn't help you on Windows. It's hard to install development tools on Windows. That's the main reason I don't use Windows.